# Scala or Python to Build a Comet server to support a PHP application?

Tags: javascript, python, scala, node.js, comet

I have a currently running PHP application that I want to add real-time feed (Google search latest result feeds), I have an implementation in PHP that does the following:

1. An AJAX request to the server.
2. The PHP responds.
3. After 15000ms (15 seconds) using setTimeout(), we repeat the steps.

I knew this have very much overhead on the server and will cause the C10K problems.

After researching I figured out that PHP as an Apache2 module is incompetent to implement the Comet solutions which is unfortunate!

I have two options, to use Scala, or Use Python to implement this part of my website since it's all complete and there is no time for rewriting it.

I don't care for anything as I care for performance since I use VPS200 from [ServerGrove](http://www.servergrove.com/vps), And I'm going to install JVM or Python side-by-side with PHP.

So what you think has less memory/CPU consumption in this case JVM with Scala, Or Python?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
I guess I'll use [Akka Project](http://akkasource.org/), I'm going to test it.

**Update 2:**
I've done it using [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org/), it's incomparable by any other solution (IMO) in learning curve, community support, and project maturity. And I had an unfortunate experience with Scala since I a gave Scala a very long opportunity before trying Node.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)? It has a proven reputation of the solution that perfectly handles COMET. Everyone knows [Plurk success story](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1088699) - one of the most popular social networking sites in Asia that has 500+mln subscribers, with up to 200k of them working in a parallel (using COMET long-polling connections). node.js memory usage is way better (~10 times less) compared to [solutions based on java app server suitable for COMET (Jetty/Netty)](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19456).

If you finally want to go with Java/Scala, you should first of all have a look at [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.dev.java.net/) framework. It has the richest feature-set these days (supports all kinds of COMET strategies + web-sockets + servlets 3.0); [out-of-the-box REST-support, based on Jersey](http://java.dzone.com/articles/writing-comet-applications) (implementation of JAX-RS specification); [integration with Akka](http://doc.akkasource.org/comet) (very powerful implementation of actors, fault-tolerance, STM, remotings etc on Scala).

Choosing a Lift, you'd probably have to re-write your application entirely, though it has a very good COMET support.

Comment: I can't in any case take the chance of rewriting, at least not this time! it's purely MVC and I suspect I'd be able to just convert it!

Comment: Update: after doing it in Node.js, it turns out it is the perfect solution for web apps. Because of the two sides (server, and client) in JS.

Answer (score 2):

Scala with lift (lliftweb.org) will have better opportunity for performance.  Comet support in Lift is excellent.  You should test them both though with a small prototype and compare.